# Python function for joining sentences in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the requirement of joining all the words using underscore.

Input

```
test = ["Hello", "World", "Test me"]
```

Output

```
"Hello_World_Test_me"
```

What is the best way to achieve this in python3 ?

Comment: @Asocia I already did and have couple of options. I just wanted to check best approach since simple join will not help here and I don't want to nest or do list comprehension

Comment: I just realized that a plain `str.join` would not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the array using `'_'.join(list)` and then replace space with `_`

```
test = ["Hello", "World", "Test me"]

res = '_'.join(test).replace(' ', '_')
print(res)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
"_".join(w for word in test for w in word.split())
```

python string's join method joins the provided list with the string on which it is called upon.

Comment: this gives me the output as "Hello_World_Test me"

Comment: ```print("_".join([w for word in test for w in word.split()]))``` If you want each word in the list separated by space to be joined by underscore then use this snippet

Comment: You don't need to construct a list (`[]`). Just a generator expression would be faster.